# Springfox - Manually, programmatically adding model

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I would like to add a custom controller to swagger API descriptor.
It's quite easy with spring fox to a custom existing model.
But I don't succeed to add custom API to swagger descriptor from scratch.
An example is better than a long speech.

I did a test project [springfox-test](https://github.com/BetterOfToffy/springfox-test.git)

I have a controller (ItemController) who handle two URLs (`/item/name` and `/item/number`) and return two different beans (`ItemName` and `ItemNumber`).

It wasn't that hard to add both Operations to Swagger through an ApiListingScannerPlugin implementation, but I had to make reference to my beans (ItemName and ItemNumber), and I don't know how and where I can describe these beans.

The ApiListingBuilderPlugin class seems to work that way, but we can only access the builder of the API and then I have to override all models.

Is there a way to ask spring fox to describe these beans?

Comment: I found this : https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1216 but adding my models through docket.additionalModels() method does not make any differences.